# Specify arithmetic operation before backing type is known?

Tags: scala, lambda, type-parameter

I'm trying to write an interface through which users should be able to pass arbitrary arithmetic functions independent of numeric type, and then helper code would bind them to appropriate backing `Numeric` used by the system. (The need for this is complicated, but it's a DSL design thing and the numeric type which will ultimately be used is not known at compile time, though it can be restricted to a small set.)

So the goal is to get something like:

```
case class numericOp(
  intVersion : (Int, Int) -> Int,
  floatVersion : (Float, Float) -> Float
)
def wrap(f : ???) : NumericOp = NumericOp(f[Int], f[Float])

//use site
wrap( (x, y) => x + y)

//use in engine
def applyArithmetic(arg1 : Any, arg2 : Any, op : NumericOp) : Any{
  (arg1, arg2) match {
    case (a : Int, b : Int) => op.intVersion(a, b)
    case (a : Float, b : Float) => op.floatVersion(a, b)
    case _ => throw new Exception("Invalid types") //shouldn't actually be reachable

}
```

The above - which obviously doesn't compile - would have `wrap` take a generic lambda with an un-applied type parameter, and then apply the backing types to it to create real functions.

I understand why this doesn't work - type parameter application would have to happen before runtime, i.e., before the lambda even exists. That said, the core of what I'm trying to do - describe arithmetic logic as data, then create specific implementations later once a type is available - seems like it should be possible. (My reasoning is that I could describe a complete DSL of all operations under `Numeric`, have users specify their math in that DSL, and then create implementations for `Int`/`Float`/`Whatever` later.)

Is there a way to make this work?

I very much want to keep the use site concise, and more importantly, abstracted from the backing types.

To give some more explicit detail and requirements:

1. First, the user specifies their arithmetic operation in some type-agnostic way. It's fine for them to know they're dealing in some `Numeric` type, but the should not have to know the specific type, or even the number of possible types. I don't know what format this input could take, thus the ??? in the code.
2. Their specification - call this `f` - is passed to a handler function (`wrap`, above). This function can know the set of possible backing types, and produces an intermediate structure to store any needed type-specific data (`numericOp`, above)
3. The intermediate structure gets used in an interpreter that operates over dynamic `Any` values (type checking is done on the input DSL code, and casting is done when needed). This is done in `applyArithmetic`, above.

To take a more temporal view of it:

1. The user specifies some arithmetic logic, passing it into the `wrap` function
2. The system maintainer re-arranges the set of possible backing numeric types, adding/removing them without telling the user
3. The code is compiled
4. During runtime, the specific values are passed to an `applyArithmetic` function as `Any`s along with whatever intermediate type `wrap` output.

Comment: Not entirely sure to understand your ultimate goal but do you know there's a `Numeric` typeclass already existing in Scala?

Comment: @GaëlJ Yeah, but I don't see a way to use it here - my understanding is that that gives me a way to specify the logic in a generic way in the code, but I can't pass that generic specification around as a parameter.

Comment: @EdwardPeters you certainly CAN pass a `Numeric` instance around as a parameter, implicit or explicit.

Comment: @Dima Can you demonstrate? My understanding is that the `Numeric` would have to be resolved to a specific type at compile time, which isn't an option for me..

Comment: I guess giving more details about how `wrap` and `applyArithmetic` would be called will help us guide you.

Comment: `[T : Numeric](arg1: T, arg2: T) = ...` - in compile time method body would know that operation on arguments are resolved to method in some `Numeric[T]` passed as an (implicit) argument. What this argument would be depends on the call site, so by passing it on long enough, you have a type-safe code where implementation is decided on in runtime (by implicits doing DI). This is called tagless final (simplifying). Alternative is some free algebra where you would "record" sequence of operations as data, and later "reply" them with actual implementation.

Comment: @GaëlJ I added some additional description.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I'm not sure where the code snippet you show would go, exactly. I understand how the call site could resolve to a hard-coded function with generic parameters, but not how that function could exist as a parameter to be passed around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use something like `Numeric[Int]` compiler will resolve it in compile time to some value and then use it. So it would be hardcoded as you suspect.

```
def func(arg1: Int, arg2: Int): Int = {
  Numeric[Int].plus(arg1, arg2)
}
```

The same would not be true though if you did:

```
def func[T: Numeric](arg1: T, arg2: T): T = {
  Numeric[T].plus(arg1, arg2)
}
```

Why?

```
def func[T: Numeric](arg1: T, arg2: T): T = ...
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
def func[T](arg1: T, arg2: T)(implicit generatedName: Numeric[T]): T = ...
```

Therefore

```
def numericOp[T: Numeric](arg1: T, arg2: T): T = {
  Numeric[T].plus(arg1, arg2)
}

numericOp(1, 2)
numericOp(1L, 2L)
numericOp(1.0, 2.0)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
def numericOp[T](arg1: T, arg2: T)(implicit genName: Numeric[T]): T = {
  genName.plus(arg1, arg2)
}

// Integral is subtype of Numeric and implicit finds
// these implementations in Numeric companion object
numericOp(1, 2)(Numeric.IntIsIntegral)
numericOp(1L, 2L)(Numeric.LongIsIntegral)
numericOp(1.0, 2.0)(Numeric.DoubleIsIntegral)
```

If you consistently used implicits with a type class - and often also extension methods to make it more readable:

```
// Scala 2
implicit class NumericOps[T](private val value: T) extends AnyVal {
  
  def +(another: T)(implicit T: Numeric[T]): T = T.plus(value, another)
}

// Scala 3
extension [T](value: T)
  def +(another: T)(implicit T: Numeric[T]): T = T.plus(value, another)
```

this parametrized interface with implementation resolved for the type - deferring the specification of `T` (and resolving implicit to value of known type) it's an example of something called tagless final.

Alternative is to use free algebra:

```
sealed trait NumericExpr[T] {

  import NumericExpr._

  def + (another: NumericExpr[T]): NumericExpr[T] =
    Plus(this, another)
  def - (another: NumericExpr[T]): NumericExpr[T] =
    Minus(this, another)

  def run(plus: (T, T) => T)(minus: (T, T) => T): T = this match {
    case Value(t) => t
    case Plus(a, b) => plus(run(a), run(b))
    case Minus(a, b) => minus(run(a), run(b))
  }
}
object NumericExpr {
  case class Value[T](number: T) extends NumericExpr
  case class Plus[T](a: NumericExpr[T], b: a: NumericExpr[T]) extends NumericExpr
  case class Minus[T](a: NumericExpr[T], b: a: NumericExpr[T]) extends NumericExpr

  def wrap[T](t: T): NumericExpr[T] = Value(t)
}
```

The way you use it is to wrap all values in this wrapper type, and let this wrapper type "record" operations (without knowing the exact implementation) which you would later "replay" providing implementation as the last step.

```
// generic code works with free algebra
def numericOp[T](arg1: NumericExpr[T], arg2: NumericExpr[T]): NumericExpr[T] = {
  arg1 + arg2
}

// specific code lifts values into free algebra and later provide implementation
numericOp(NumericExpr.wrap(1), NumericExpr.warp(2)).run(_ + _)(_ - _)
```

EDIT:

If you want tagless final-like approach there are 2 options:

Scala 2:

```
// There are no polymorphic methods in Scala 2
// and neither there are funtions with implicits
// - we you have to attach such method to an interface
trait numericOps {
  def apply[T: Numeric](t1: T, t2: T): T
}

val plus: numericOps = new numericOps {
  def apply[T: Numeric](t1: T, t2: T): T = Numeric[T].plus(t1, t2)
}

plus2(1, 2)
```

Scala 3:

```
// Has both polymorphic function types as well
// as context functions
type numericOps = [T] => (T, T) => Numeric[T] ?=> T

val plus: numericOps = [T] => (t1: T, t2: T) => (num: Numeric[T]) ?=> num.plus(t1, t2)

plus(1, 2)
```

See [demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/T8KsIcFlQpWeknbl9lpFSw).

Comment: So I'm staring at your tagless-final approach and I think it makes sense to me, but it still doesn't look like it can go all the way to what I'm describing - there's never a function that can take an un-specified `numericOp` on its interface.  i.e., you have `def func[T: Numeric](arg1: T, arg2: T): T = {  Numeric[T].plus(arg1, arg2)}`, but nothing can take that as an argument and then bind it with specific `T` types later. The free algebra approach matches what I need, but requires re-specifying the entire AST I want coverage of..

Comment: Well, you can make your functions with classes and then deferring type parameters to class' `def apply[T: Numeric]` is easier (`trait NumericOp { def apply[T: Numeric](t1: T, t2: T): T }`). Or - if you're on Scala 3 - there are polymorphic function types and context functions `[T] => Numeric[T] ?=> (T, T) => T`.

Comment: If you will have a lot of operations, you can import [`NumericOps`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html#mkNumericOps(lhs:T):Numeric.this.NumericOps) from the `num` to be able to write something like `t1 + t2` inside this functions. I only focused on the abstraction part but from there on you can read about extension method so that this style will not be annoying to write.